# How to get profile link instagram by user_id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How to get profile link or username instagram by user_id?
without using services
without API

Comment: if someone is useful: https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/{user_id}/follow/

Answer (score 0):

You may use 3rd party services. Other than that you must call users endpoint to work the username out.